# Adding Multiline comment in Powershell

Tags: powershell, comments, multiline

How can we add multiline comment in powershell script?

$a=10
$b=20

writ-host "Sum"

Answer (score 0):

We can add multiline comment in powershell as below

**<#**

$a=10

$b=20

writ-host "Sum"

**#>**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, PowerShell supports multi-line block comments:

```
<#
$a=10
$b=20

Write-Host "Sum"
#>
```

Do note that block comments are *non-nestable*:

```
<# 
This is part of the comment
<#
$a=10
$b=20

Write-Host "Sum"
#>
But this is not...
#>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<#` and `#>` symbols to create a comment block.

```
<#
    $a=10
    $b=20

    writ-host "Sum"
#>
```

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/help/syntax-of-comment-based-help?view=powershell-7.1